# Php GCM Push notification with iOS

Tags: php, ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push notification from php using GCM. Receiver is a iOS device. I am not receiving the notification from iOS device but if I try with PostMan I am getting it. I am getting success in php API -

> {"multicast_id":6620946920649682270,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1452841688393271%bcdb604df9fd7ecd"}]}

**What I wrote in php**

```
<?php
// Your API key
$api_key = "sgvdahgsvasbjbsKqaFHap4PC745ezKBS47Xs0QZV8";

// Client IDs from your application
$registration_ids = array( "lojInK-jPug:APA91bFnmo81ue-   GRdByVZVn_QSY8jpTHJnsdasdkasdkRwRnJ9gE4fQtfI_VfxfGSuCFhQIriem84HI9nTWEqXfRblHz_YkqHOMnzjBgvPRp8pRWeDm3fVO9a5w3MtsMUf" );

$message = "hello, test!!";

// URL to POST to
$gcm_url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

// data to be posted
$fields = array(
            'registration_ids'  => $registration_ids,
            'data'              => array( "message" => '"notification" :{"sound":"default","badge":"2","body":"Test Push!"}' ),
            );

 // headers for the request
 $headers = array( 
                'Authorization: key=' . $api_key,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            );

 $curl_handle = curl_init();

 // set CURL options
 curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL, $gcm_url );

 curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_POST, true );
 curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

 curl_setopt( $curl_handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields )      );

 // send
 echo $response = curl_exec($curl_handle);

 curl_close($curl_handle);

// let's check the response
$data = json_decode($response);

foreach ($data['results'] as $key => $value) {
if ($value['registration_id']) {
    printf("%s has a new registration id: %s\r\n", $key, $value['registration_id']);
}
if ($value['error']) {
    printf("%s encountered error: %s\r\n", $key, $value['error']);
}
if ($value['message_id']) {
    printf("%s was successfully sent, message id: %s", $key, $value['message_id']);
}
}
?>
```

**In iOS what I tried -**

```
@UIApplicationMain

class AppDelegate: UIResponder,UIApplicationDelegate,AsyncDataProviderDelegate,GGLInstanceIDDelegate {



var window: UIWindow?



var successToken = ""

var launchOpt : NSDictionary?

var rootControllerVC : UIViewController?



func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {



    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor()], forState:.Normal)

    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor(red: 10.00/255.00, green: 32.00/255.00, blue: 32.00/255.00, alpha: 1)], forState:.Selected)



    let tabFont = UIFont(name:"Helvetica-Bold", size: 12)



    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.whiteColor(), NSFontAttributeName: tabFont!], forState:.Normal)



    if #available(iOS 8.0, *)

    {



        let types:UIUserNotificationType = ([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])

        let settings:UIUserNotificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: types, categories: nil)

        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)

        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()

    } else

    {

        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes([.Alert, .Sound, .Badge])

    }



    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0



    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.delegate = self



    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    return true

}



func callRegisterAPi(regId : String)

{

    let detailDict = NSMutableDictionary()



    detailDict.setObject(kDeviceType, forKey:deviceType)

    detailDict.setObject(kDeviceId, forKey:deviceId)

    detailDict.setObject(regId, forKey: registerID)

    detailDict.setObject(kguiVersion, forKey:guiVersion)



    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.registerDeviceApi("POST", isAsynchronous: true, userDictionary: detailDict)



}







//MARK:- AsyncData Provider delgate



func dataGivenBack(resultDataDict: NSMutableDictionary, methodName: String) {



    if successToken != ""

    {

        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(successToken, forKey:kToken)



    }



}



//MARK:- Push Notification Delegate Methods



func application(application: UIApplication,didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData)

{

    let characterSet: NSCharacterSet = NSCharacterSet( charactersInString: "<>" )

    let deviceTokenString: String = ( deviceToken.description as NSString ).stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet( characterSet ).stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString( " ",withString: "" ) as String



    print("token is \(deviceTokenString)")







    // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.

    let instanceIDConfig = GGLInstanceIDConfig.defaultConfig()

    instanceIDConfig.delegate = self

    // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with that config and request a registration

    // token to enable reception of notifications

    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().startWithConfig(instanceIDConfig)

    let registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,

        kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]



    let gcmSenderID = "83985659474"



    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,

        scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions, handler: registrationHandler)



}



func registrationHandler(registrationToken: String!, error: NSError!) {

    if (registrationToken != nil) {



        successToken = registrationToken



        print("GCM Token is :\(registrationToken)")



        if isDeviceTokenChanged(registrationToken)

        {

            callRegisterAPi(registrationToken)

        }



        print("Registred")

    } else {

        print("Registration to GCM failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")

    }

}



func onTokenRefresh() {





    let registrationOptions = [kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:successToken,

        kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:true]



    let gcmSenderID = "83985659474"



    // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.

    print("The GCM registration token needs to be changed.")

    GGLInstanceID.sharedInstance().tokenWithAuthorizedEntity(gcmSenderID,

        scope: kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM, options: registrationOptions as [NSObject : AnyObject], handler: registrationHandler)

}



//Called if unable to register for APNS.

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError)

{

    print("not registered to APNS,\(error)")

}



func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

{



     GCMService.sharedInstance().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo);



    print("Receiving dict is :\(userInfo)")



    rootControllerVC  = mainStoryBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("startingPage") as UIViewController

    self.window?.rootViewController = rootControllerVC

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0



    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData)



}



func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {

    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.

    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.

}



func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {

    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.

    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.

}



func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {

    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.

}



func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {

    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.





    GCMService.sharedInstance().connectWithHandler({

        (NSError error) -> Void in

        if error != nil {

            print("Could not connect to GCM: \(error.localizedDescription)")

        } else

        {

            //self.connectedToGCM = true

            print("Connected to GCM")

            // ...

        }

    })

}



func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {

    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.

}
}
```

Comment: Last time I checked GCM was only meant for Android devices, not iOS. For iOS there is similar solution, but from Apple - Apple Push Notification. You can also try unified AWS Push Notification Service from Amazon (SNS) for all mobile platforms.

Comment: I have specific requirement I have to use GCM becoz Android side is already ready it's working also.

Comment: Any thanks for your reply and suggestion @BartoszMoczulski